# "Can Not Parse the WSDL file" error in PowerBuilder 12

Tags: powerbuilder

In my application i am trying to use a web service for the credit card processing. I am using 3DSI WSDL to perform the task. The problem is, whenever I am trying to go through the Web Service Wizard, keeping the link and hitting the service button, PB is throwing an error, "Can Not Parse the WSDL file". I tried both with EasySoap and .net. But the result is same.

My WSDL links are mentioned below:

https://services.PWSDemo.com/CreditCardTransactionService.svc
https://services.PWSDemo.com/CreditCardTransactionService.svc?wsdl

Credit Card Transaction Processing
https://services.PaymentWorkSuite.com/CreditCardTransactionService.svc
https://services.PaymentWorkSuite.com/CreditCardTransactionService.svc?wsdl

can anybody please tell me what extra I need to do before I can access a WSDL file, or is it a PB error?

Regards,
Manab

Comment: You might try saving a copy of the wsdl to your computer and try to get PB to read it from there.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, i created the file locally and was able to get the services within my pbl.

Answer (score 0):

Too late, but might still help other PB users around, like me who spend almost a day trying to figure out what was wrong. The answer/reply given by [@Slapout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19072/slapout)
worked like a charm. Wonder why nobody marked it as answer.

> You might try saving a copy of the wsdl to your computer and try to
>   get PB to read it from there.